# how can I update an existing column from an action except update?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to update a column of an existing record, hopefully, with one action, but since I could not do that, now there are two actions.

### In detail

make users specify a number to add to an existing column like
if a user specifies 3, and the existing column is 97, then in total 100 and the number, 100 will be saved.

view `split_now.html.erb`

```
<div class="container">
 <h1>Split</h1>
 <%= form_for @currency, url: { action: 'split', controller: 'currencies'}, method: :put do |f|%>
  <% if @currency.errors.any? %>
      <div id="error_explanation" class="alert alert-danger">
        <h2><%= @currency.errors.count %>error(s) exist(s).</h2>
        <ul>
          <% @currency.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
              <li><%= msg %></li>
          <% end %>
        </ul>
      </div>
  <% end %>
  <p>amount whatever you want to issue like 100</p>
  <div class="input-group">
    <%= f.text_field :amount,:class=>'form-control form-group',placeholder:"amount"%>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit 'done', class: "btn btn-large bg-info" %>
 <% end %>
</div>   


def split_now
  @currency=Currency.find_by_slug(params[:id])
end


def split
   @currency=Currency.find_by_slug(params[:id])
  if CurrencyUser.where(currency_id:@currency.id,owner:true).first.user==current_user
   if SplitValidation.new(amount:params[:amount]).valid?
    issue_more(params,@currency)
    else
    render "split_now"
    end
  else
    redirect_to @currency,alert:"This currency wasn't issued by you"
  end
end

def issue_more(params,currency)
   result=false
   current_amount=currency.amount
  result=currency.update(
            amount:current_amount+params[:amount].to_i
  )
 currency_user=CurrencyUser.find_by(currency_id:currency.id,owner:true)
 currency_user.update(amount:currency_user.amount+params[:amount].to_i)
 return result
end`
```

this is the validator

```
class SplitValidation

 include ActiveModel::Model
 attr_accessor :amount
 validates :amount, presence: true,numericality: { only_integer:  true,greater_than: 0 }

end
```

routes

```
 resources :currencies do
  member do
    put :split
    get :split_now
  end
 end
```

Comment: Could `currency_user.increment!(:amount, params[:amount].to_i)` be what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to the following, I think you want to like this:

```
currency_user.increment('amount', params[:amount].to_i)
```

or

```
currency_user.increment!('amount', params[:amount].to_i)
```

or

```
currency_user.update_attributes({'amount': currency_user.amount + params[:amount].to_i})
```

or

```
currency_user.update_attribute(amount: currency_user.amount + params[:amount].to_i)
```

**Update**

The following methods skip validations and will save the object to the database regardless of its validity. They should be used with caution. [`Skipping Validations`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#skipping-validations)

**Update 2**

For validation, you can use HTML default validator `<input type="number" min="1" name="number" step="1" required/>`, see the below code with `alert` example, just push to run and see what's happen.

```js
$(document).on('submit', '#myForm', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var formData = $(this).serialize();
    alert(formData);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myForm" action="//google.com">
  <p>Input type number step any</p>  
  <input type="number" min="1" name="number" step="1" required/>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Hope it will work.

Comment: Can I validate the params to increment before I increment?

Comment: The following methods skip validations, and will save the object to the database regardless of its validity. They should be used with caution. [Skipping Validations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#skipping-validations)

Comment: So aren't there any ways to validate the given param before updating? I want to forbid users to enter negative numbers and decimal numbers

Comment: You can see the ***Update 2*** section. "I want to forbid users to enter negative numbers and decimal numbers" that has solved on this

Comment: Aren't there any concerns that somome forges the HTML somehow?